# OutOfMemory Error , Too much library files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing a project, which uses a module(library project). Independently both are working fine, but when I am integrating both they starts to throw error in gradle build.

**Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.commom.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExceException: Process 'command'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe" finished with non-zero exit value 2**

I have almost same import of library set in both the modules, because of security issues I needed to put these modules seperately.

Following are the build.gradle files for both

app : build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*************************"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/khandroid-httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

library : build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6'


}
```

I had already enabled **multidexedenabled true** .

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.Following are the steps I take:

1) In gradle.properties file of project un-comment the line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And write : `org.gradle.daemon=true`

2)In my project module app:build.gradle, I removed all the dependencies that has been there in library's build.gradle file.